# Drawing area using cairo

Tags: gtk, cpu-usage, cairo

I am developing a simple interface which simulates a led using GTK3 and C. When I receive a command the "led" turn on or turn off according to command. I am using Cairo in drawing area to draw a circle representing my led and I am using gtk_widget_queue_draw_area to update screen in my timeout function. After a while my CPU usage increase to 100% in my application.

When I receive a command I call the function below

```
void update_status_led(int led, int status_led)
{

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea[led]), "draw", G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event_leds), GINT_TO_POINTER(status_led));

}
```

so the callback function "on_draw_event_leds" is called

```
gboolean on_draw_event_leds(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, 
    gpointer user_data)
{ 
  set_status_led(cr, GPOINTER_TO_INT(user_data));
  return FALSE;
}
```

So it calls the function "set_status_led"

```
void set_status_led(cairo_t *cr, int status)
{
    printf("update status led: %d\n", countref++);
    cairo_reference(cr);
    cairo_set_line_width(cr, 2);  
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
    cairo_arc(cr, 9, 9, 7, 0, 2 * M_PI);
    if (status>0)
    {
      cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 0, 0); //red
    }
    else
    {
      cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0); //black
    }
    cairo_fill(cr);
    cairo_stroke(cr);
    cairo_destroy(cr);
}
```

I am using "printf("update status led: %d\n", countref++);" to know how many times my function is called and my log is printed below

```
New Connection from 127.0.0.1:34589
1 Command Received
update status led: 6
update status led: 7
1 Command Received
update status led: 8
update status led: 9
update status led: 10
1 Command Received
update status led: 11
update status led: 12
update status led: 13
update status led: 14
1 Command Received
update status led: 15
update status led: 16
update status led: 17
update status led: 18
update status led: 19
1 Command Received
update status led: 20
update status led: 21
update status led: 22
update status led: 23
update status led: 24
update status led: 25
1 Command Received
...
```

As can be seen, I receive only one command and my callback function on_draw_event_leds is called many times and always increase 1 more call 
each received command as previous cairo was not deleted and gtk_widget_queue_draw_area render them all again.

Can someone help me?

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it, but you have two big mistakes. First, do not call `cairo_reference()` and `cairo_destroy()`; you do not own the `cairo_t` that you get from the `draw` callback. Second, `cairo_fill()` clears the current path, so your `cairo_stroke()` draws nothing. Use `ciaro_fill_preserve()` instead. I'll take a closer look later today.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I fixed that you said, but this didn't fix my problem. My callback function is still called many times and increasing 1 more call each received command.

Comment: Ah, I see. You are calling `update_status_led()` on every change. `g_signal_connect()` does NOT replace any existing connection with a new one; rather, it adds a new connection to the list of existing connections. So all the signal handlers you connected before are still there. You will need to change your code to only call `g_signal_connect()` once. Perhaps store the current state in a global variable or a shared variable passed around through the last `gpointer` parameter to the signal function and use `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` to schedule a redraw.

Comment: Just curious, @andlabs, why do you like to answer in comments? Nothing wrong with it, I just wanted to know if you don't want the rep or something.

Comment: To not waste answers on things that are actually wrong if I'm not fully sure of what's going on. (I think it's this. Does this solve it? *Yes it does.* Okay, here's the answer, in a more fleshed-out and detailed form.) Also partially a habit from the `winapi` tag. Admittedly this question should be answered by what I said; I can write up a more thorough answer too, but right now I'm busy with IRL stuff.

Comment: Thanks andlabs. This really solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `g_signal_connect()` function just says "when this event happens, do this function". You were likely confusing it for `gtk_widget_queue_draw()`, which is the function that actually causes a widget to be redrawn.

Somewhat counter-intuitively, signal connections are many-many. This means that any number of functions can connect to the same signal, and *all of them will be called when that signal is emitted*. Because you call `g_signal_connect()` repeatedly, you get multiple connections to your drawing function, and that drawing function will thus be called multiple times.

So what you want to do is move the `g_signal_connect()` to your initialization code instead, as that's usually where signals are connected anyway, and have `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` (or a similar function) in `update_status_led()`.